# Using Microsoft azure blob space

Tags: php, azure, azure-blob-storage

Our team have developed application using codeigniter.

A website for providing large number of large images.

We used Microsoft azure server space and Ubuntu server.

Now we want to use azure blob space to store images for downloading ,uploading and deleting process.

Does Microsoft azure blob storage supports Linux(Ubuntu) server?.

I am unable to find a beneficial document.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can certainly access Azure Blob storage from Ubuntu or any other platform that can issue REST calls:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dd135733.aspx

In addition, there are a number of language-specific libraries and bindings that wrap the REST APIs and make it easier to add/remove/manage blobs in .NET, Java, Node.js, and others:

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/storage-dotnet-how-to-use-blobs/

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/storage-java-how-to-use-blob-storage/

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/storage-nodejs-how-to-use-blob-storage/

Good luck!

Comment: i had implemented that successfully. Your information helped me.